# How to create a custom manager in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am looking for custom manager in blackberry which is using 5 different field in a row. And all the fields should be interactive. I have pasted the image of what i am looking to implement using blackberry 5.0 SDK. Please help to start with

[image]

Comment: create a main hfm .add the first field in it. then add two different vfm and one field onto that main vfm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this - [image]

Try the following code-

```
    import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;


public class scree_align extends MainScreen{

public scree_align(){

    HorizontalFieldManager hfm_main=new HorizontalFieldManager();/*{
         protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
          { 
              super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),200); setExtent(Display.getWidth(),200);
          }
      };*/

    HorizontalFieldManager hfm_1=new HorizontalFieldManager();
    final Bitmap back = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image.png");
    hfm_1.add(new BitmapField(back));
    hfm_1.setMargin(5,5,0,0);

    VerticalFieldManager vfm_1=new VerticalFieldManager();
    ButtonField btn1=new ButtonField("Button1");
    ButtonField btn2=new ButtonField("Button1");
    vfm_1.add(btn1);
    vfm_1.add(btn2);


    VerticalFieldManager vfm_2=new VerticalFieldManager();
    ButtonField btn3=new ButtonField("Button2");
    ButtonField btn4=new ButtonField("Button2");
    vfm_2.add(btn3);
    vfm_2.add(btn4);


    HorizontalFieldManager hfm_2=new HorizontalFieldManager();
    LabelField lab=new LabelField("Text");
    hfm_2.add(lab);
    hfm_2.setMargin(30,0,0,5);

    hfm_main.add(hfm_1);
    hfm_main.add(vfm_1);
    hfm_main.add(vfm_2);
    hfm_main.add(hfm_2);

    add(hfm_main);

}

}
```

Comment: Instead of giving hard code margins use FIELD_VCENTRE or Drastyle.RIGHT. for hfm_2. Because for different screen resolutions margins will be different.

Comment: @HrushikeshSalkade.. I have used Drawstyle.RIGHT for hfm_2 but it is not taking the hfm2 to right. it appears adjacent to vfm. plz help